# How to execute function inside a string

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code

```
    function render(img, name, price) {
        var row = `
            <a class="ProductCard" href="#" onclick="page('${numberFolder}')">
            <img src="${img}">
            <h1>${name}</h1>
            <p>${price}</p>
            </a>
        `;
    document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
    }
```

I want to execute the `page()` function but I can't, JavaScript detects it as a new function because it's inside the string. When I check the error I get this

> Uncaught ReferenceError: page is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

this is the `page()` function (not finished yet)

```
function page(folderNum){
    rowOrder = `HTML-HERE`
    const productDetails = database.ref(`/products/${folderNum}`);
    productDetails.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const details = snapshot.val();
    console.log(details)
   })
}
```

Comment: i tried chatGPT but it didnt help

Comment: Are you sure that `page` exists and is in scope at the time the click event happens?  You might want to read _[How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)_.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes.

Comment: There is no `page` function defined in scope in the code given here. Please read how to create a [mre] if it is defined in scope in your page.

Comment: Where is that `page` function defined? Can you add it to your example code?

Comment: @Pipe done, the function aint finished aint

Comment: But are those functions defined in the same scope?

Comment: There is also no `numberFolder` variable present at render time.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `page` function is not in scope when you click the added content.  Because if it's placed correctly, this technique should work fine, as the following snippet demonstrates:

```js
function render(title, value) {
   const row = `
     <div>
       <a class="ProductCard" href="#" onclick="page('${value}')">
         <p>${title}: ${value}</p>
       </a>
     </div>`;
    document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
}

function page(x) {
  alert(x)
}

render ('Meaning of life', 42)
render ('Bottles of beer', 99)
```

```html
<div id="main"><h3>Click these to see that it works</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the `a` tag by doing for example: `let aTag = row.children[0]`. Than you can do: `aTag.onclick = () => page('${numberFolder}')`. This is probably the safest way to do it. For solid and change proof code you can select the aTag by querying on a class name.

Edit: You don't need to define functions in text and you really shouldn't ever.

Comment: There is no evidence from the question that the function is defined in text, only that the call to it is in text.  While I would argue that there are better ways to do this, the technique as described should work if `page` is a function in scope at the time of the event.  I personally have used the Function constructor (strings -> function) to good effect in certain metaprogramming techniques.  But that doesn't look necessary here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I certainly understand what you mean and I completely agree, strictly speaking however, in this case, you do define a function ;) : namely `(event) => page('${numberFolder}')"(event)` in this case. Unless of course `page` returns a function. The function is available in the window, else what he is trying to do wouldn't be possible at all. Thus either its in the same script file or it can be accessed.

Comment: By scope here, I only meant that the implementation of `page` is not stuck inside some function.  There will be no closure capturing it for such string-derived handler functions, and probably not for any inline handlers.